# dropdownlist does not load chain

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a method that fills dropdownlist with values based on your previous choice:

```
private void CarregarCombos(DropDownList dropDown)
{
    dropDown.Items.Clear();

    dynamic resultados = null;

    switch (dropDown.ID)
    {
        case "ddlOrgaoProdutor":
            dropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem("0000 - Todos os Órgãos", ""));
            OrgaoProdutor bllOPR = new OrgaoProdutor();
            resultados = new List<OrgaoProdutorInfo>();
            resultados = bllOPR.ListarOrgaoProdutorPorStatus("1,2").OrderBy(n => n.Numero).ToList();
            break;

        case "ddlFuncao":
            dropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem("Selecione", ""));
            Funcao bllFuncao = new Funcao();
            resultados = new List<FuncaoInfo>();
            resultados = bllFuncao.ListarPorOrgaoProdutor(DataParser.ToInt(ddlOrgaoProdutor.SelectedValue), 1).OrderBy(n => n.Numero).ToList();
            break;

        case "ddlSubFuncao":
            dropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem("Selecione", ""));
            SubFuncao bllSubFuncao = new SubFuncao();
            resultados = new List<SubFuncaoInfo>();
            resultados = bllSubFuncao.ListarSubFuncao(DataParser.ToInt(ddlOrgaoProdutor.SelectedValue), DataParser.ToInt(ddlFuncao.SelectedValue), 1).OrderBy(n => n.Numero).ToList();
            break;

        case "ddlAtividade":
            dropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem("Selecione", ""));
            Atividade bllAtividade = new Atividade();
            resultados = new List<AtividadeInfo>();
            resultados = bllAtividade.ListarAtividades(DataParser.ToInt(ddlOrgaoProdutor.SelectedValue), DataParser.ToInt(ddlFuncao.SelectedValue), DataParser.ToInt(ddlSubFuncao.SelectedValue), 1).OrderBy(n => n.Numero).ToList();
            break;
    }


    foreach (var item in resultados)
        dropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem(string.Format("{0} - {1}", item.Numero.ToString(), item.Descricao), item.Codigo.ToString()));

}
```

My Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        CarregarCombos(ddlOrgaoProdutor);
        CarregarCombos(ddlFuncao);
    }
}
```

Just first dropdown is filled in front-end, but in code-behind all work perfectly, because in other steps of application the method works normally. Would be a rendering problem?
A detail: when I chain around the visible only the first is enabled.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the below code you're adding a new `ListItem` with `Text = 0000 - Todos os Órgãos` and `Value as ""` for `ddlOrgaoProdutor (the parent dropdown)`

```
case "ddlOrgaoProdutor":
        dropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem("0000 - Todos os Órgãos", ""));
```

And for the data for all other dropdownlists you are filtering data based on `ddlOrgaoProdutor1's SelectedValue` which is defined as `""`. May be you need send in as or set the actual value for `ddlOrgaoProdutor`

```
resultados = bllFuncao.ListarPorOrgaoProdutor(DataParser.ToInt(ddlOrgaoProdutor.SelectedText), 1).OrderBy(n => n.Numero).ToList();
```

Also, you're filling the dropdownlists during initial pageload (`if (!IsPostBack) .. )`which is not going to be triggered when the value of the ddlOrgaoProdutor changes. If you need to rebind all the drowdowns when the value for `ddlOrgaoProdutor` changes then you need set `OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOrgaoProdutor_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"` and from the event call the function `CarregarCombos` for all the other dropdowns.

```
 protected void ddlOrgaoProdutor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     DropDownList ddlFuncao= (DropDownList)Page.FindControl("ddlFuncao");
     CarregarCombos(ddlFuncao);

     // find other dropdownlists and call the function CarregarCombos
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! but the problem was a Panel with property Enable = false.